# Changing form_row

Tags: symfony, twig

Can someone help me to tranform this line:

```
<li>{{ form_row(form.features_reducing_value)  }}</li>
```

to this or something like this :

```
<div id="dynamicInput">
      Entry 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
 </div>
 <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to be able to clone your form fields. In Symfony this is done using form collections and embedding them with "prototype".

More information is here -> http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 0):

for instance to override the `<input type="number" />` you do like this:

```
{# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block integer_widget %}
    <div class="integer_widget">
        {% set type = type|default('number') %}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And in your html.twig file you use the from_theme like this:

```
{% form_theme form 'AcmeDemoBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}
```

more information about that [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)